# Read values from the Office 2007 ribbon using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon, office-2007

Using VBA, can I find out the value of a text (combobox) control on the Word 2007 ribbon?

Say I'd want to read the currently selected font name in the "Home" tab.

I've seen an example using the [`IAccessible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/accessibility.iaccessible.aspx) interface to do *some* interaction with the Ribbon (namely enumerating it), but it seems reading a control value is not possible. Is there another way to do it, or is VBA locked out completely?

Comment: http://www.wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.htm
That might help

Comment: That's the example I talked about... It can do some enumerating, but reading the value of a ribbon element is not possible - only triggering the "default action", like, clicking or opening the dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get at the ribbon to read the built in properties.
For you specific example of Font name you can use the following.

`Msgbox Application.Commandbars.Findcontrol(ID:=1728).Text`

You maybe able to adpat the approach for other information.